# Facebook change user page cover photo graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to change Facebook cover image of a specific page. how to change page cover image not profile cover of user. i have tried many times. i have used many code but still facing problem.

Comment: Can you show what you tried what problems you are facing ?

Comment: please add your code (NOT as screenshot) and include a much more detailed description of your problem. where exactly are you stuck? is there any error we can work with?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to upload the image you like to use to Facebook and afterwards update the page with the field "cover" set. It should be the numeric value of the image on Facebook.

Check the Graph Api reference for the Page object:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: I have uploaded image to Facebook post image is perfectly fit on profile cover. but i am trying to post on PAGE COVER Photo. do you have any idea

Comment: there is only one page cover photo, and what norbert answered is correct. maybe include a more detailed description with a screenshot in your question if that is not what you want?

Comment: I have upload what i am doing. I am in heavy trouble, kindly sort out my problem.

Comment: you always need to include all relevant details in your question, NEVER in comments. also, please don´t add code as screenshots...

Comment: Besides, it does not look as if you even attempted to implement this in there in any way. You do not even seem to be using a page access token yet, but are uploading the photo to a _user_ profile.